# SVG positioning with a small browser window

Tags: html, css, svg

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/t5rhp/7/

SVG HTML

```
<svg version="1.1" 
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
     x="0px" y="0px" 
     viewBox="0 0 1400 1120" 
     enable-background="new 0 0 1400 1120" 
     xml:space="preserve" id="city">
   <g id="bg2" enable-background="new">
...
```

SVG CSS

```
svg {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:0;
}
```

The SVG displays perfectly when the window is large, and the svg is docked to the bottom of the blue area. However, when I shrink the window down to a small width the SVG is no longer docked to the bottom and seems to sit in the center of the page, vertically.

Is there any way I can make it so that no matter how small the window, but bottom of the buildings are always sitting on the bottom of the blue box.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`preserveAspectRatio`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/coords.html#PreserveAspectRatioAttribute) attribute. Add this attribute to the `<svg>` opening tag:

```
preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMax"
```

It will keep the image centered and will keep it always at the bottom (Y max).

See: http://jsfiddle.net/helderdarocha/t5rhp/8/